# Pairs promoting diversity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime number at least three and let ${k}$ be a positive integer smaller than $p$. Given ${a}_1, \ldots, {a}_{{k}} \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and distinct elements ${b}_1, \ldots, {b}_{{k}} \in \mathbb{F}_p$, prove that there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $[{k}]$ such that the values of ${a}_{{i}}+{b}_{\sigma({i})}$ are distinct.

I am not sure if the below solution logic contains fallacy or not, but this is my progress so far:

$\textbf{Solution (so far):}$ The statement we want to prove is equivalent to the following: If $a_1,...,a_k$ and $b_1,...,b_k$ are distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}p$, there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $[k]$ such that the numbers $a_i-b_{\sigma(i)}$ are all distinct modulo $p$.

Consider all the $k!$ permutations of the $b_i$'s. For each permutation, we can form a set of k numbers of the form $a_i - b_{\sigma(i)}$. Thus we have a total of $k\,k!$ numbers.

We want to show that we must have at least $k$ distinct numbers in some set, which will be equivalent to proving the existence of a permutation such that the numbers $a_i - b_{\sigma(i)}$ are distinct.

Since these numbers are taken modulo $p$, there are only $p$ possible values. If we assume that we can't find $k$ distinct numbers in any set, then each set can have at most $k-1$ distinct numbers. Thus, in total, we would have at most $(k-1)k!$ distinct numbers.

However, we know that the total number of numbers is $k\,k!$ and this is strictly less than $p$ since $p$ is a prime number larger than $k$. Therefore, we must have $k\,k! \leq (k-1)k!$, which is a contradiction. Hence, there must exist a permutation such that the numbers $a_i - b_{\sigma(i)}$ are distinct modulo $p$.

Comment: Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: I have a question: What is the definition of $\mathbb{F}_\mathrm{p}$?

Comment: @AnneBauval I just want a solution.

Comment: Fine! Then your [bounty reason](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) ("reputable source") was not what you intended. I don't know if you can correct the banner. Never mind.

Comment: @AnneBauval I am not sure if I can modify the bounty reason. Can you solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof follows from Combinatorial Nullstellensatz: See:
[https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/alt2.pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/alt2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting for your solution to try to force a satisfying permutation out of all permutations by counting the number of distinct elements in two different ways. However your solution is incorrect.

---

Since your solution does not use $p$ is a prime, had your solution been correct, the proposition would have been true for $p=4$ as well.

Let $p=4$, $k=2$, $a_1=0, a_2=2, b_1=0, b_2=2$. There are two permutations of $\{1,2\}.$

- $\sigma$ is the identity. $\ a_1+b_{\sigma(1)}=a_2+b_{\sigma(2)}=0\bmod4.$
- $\sigma$ swaps $1$ and $2$. $\ a_1+b_{\sigma(1)}=a_2+b_{\sigma(2)}=2\bmod4.$

Hence the proposition does not hold for $p=4$. This shows that your solution cannot be correct.

When "we have a total of $k\,k!$ numbers", those numbers are not necessarily distinct. (In fact, they are probably not.) H
Although it is true that "we would have at most $(k-1)\,k!$ distinct numbers", we cannot conclude that "therefore, we must have $k\, k!\le (k-1)\,k!$". This is where your solution breaks.

---

The proposition in the question is a stronger version (where $a_i$'s need not be distinct) of the special case (where the group is of prime order) of [Snevily's conjecture](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Snevily%27s_conjecture)  It was first proved in paper *Additive Latin transversals* by Noga Alon. Snevily's conjecture was proved in 2009 by Bodan Arsovski, *A proof of Snevily's Conjecture*, Israel Journal of Mathematics, vol. 182 (2011), pp. 505-508.

Comment: Thank you for your comment on this problem. I checked the reference and it is good to see the general version of this question, but I was curious if simpler solution exists for the particular problem I have asked.

Comment: The reason to offer bounty was also to figure out if the more intuitive and easier solution would exist

Comment: Considering the paper mentioned in the answer, "Additive Latin transversals"  by Noga Alon (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02773567), proves precisely your problem with an argument less than a page long, I doubt even simpler solutions exist